# merging dataframe with unequal length

Tags: r

I have two data frame one with 50000 observation and 23 variables other one with 49999 observation and 1 variable. when I try to bind I'm getting the following error,

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, churn, value = list(`churn$X.1` =
>   c(1L,  :    replacement has 49999 rows, data has 50000

Can you help?

```
df1 <- read.table(".....", header = T, sep = "\t", na.strings = c('NA', ''))
df2 <- read.table("......", header = T, sep = "\t")
df1$churn <- cbind(df2)
```

Comment: What's your exact question? Error message is clear - you're missing one row.

Answer (score 0):

You should use merge.

```
merge(df1,df2,by=c("colname to join"));
```